# How to multiple regexes into one regex

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have 3 regex preg_match in 1 if..

I want to know if it's possible to mix 3 regex in 1?

this is my if with 3 regex :

```
if(!preg_match("#\s#",$file) && !preg_match("#\.\.\/#",$file) && (preg_match_all("#/#",$file,$match)==1)):
```

(I want: no "space" , no "../" and only 1 "/")

thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

add the needed in list point (more readable):

- no "space"
- no "../"
- 1 "/"

Comment: is one forwardslash `/` mandatory or optional?

Comment: it can be optional but the maximum is 1.

Comment: Forgot to ask, is empty string valid?

Comment: Now you're alone with 3 working answers. Don't hesitate to accept one!

Comment: Thank you for your help. with details, I can understand and learn how to build regular expressions more efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple. Let's start step by step crafting this regex:

1. First of all, let's use anchors to define begin&end of string: `^$`
2. `I want: no "space"`, we've got `\S` which matches a non-white space character: `^\S+$`
3. `no "../"`, let's add a negative lookahead `^(?!.*[.][.]/)\S+$`, note that we don't need to escape the dot inside a character class. As for the forwardslash, we'll use different delimiters
4. `one optional "/"`, we could add a negative lookahead that prevents 2 forwardslashes `^(?!(?:.*/){2})(?!.*[.][.]/)\S+$`
5. Let's define the delimiters and add the `s` modifier to match newlines with `.`: `~^(?!(?:.*/){2})(?!.*[.][.]/)\S+$~s` and here you go with an <kbd>[**online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sL5uU9)</kbd>

Comment: If empty string is valid then replace `\S+` with `\S*`

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
if (preg_match('~^(?!.*?(?: |\.\./))(?!(.*?/){2}).*$~', $file) {
  ...
}
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pW7nP2)

Comment: I think I have it have only one `/` covered

Comment: Nice, but will match `./././`

Comment: Yes it will because OP wrote `no "../"`

Comment: But maximum numbers of `/` is one

Comment: Ah good point I have bracket close at wrong place, see it fixed

Answer (score 2):

Why not this:

```
if (preg_match('~((?>[^\s/.]++|\.(?!\./))*)/?(?1)\z~A', $str))
    echo 'OK';
```

details:

```
~
(                   # capture group 1
    (?>
        [^\s./]++   # all that is not a space, a dot or a slash
      |             # OR
        \.(?!\./)   # a dot not followed by another dot and a slash
    )*
)                  
/?                  # optional /
(?1)                # repeat the capture group 1
\z                  # anchor for end of the string
~A                  # anchored pattern
```

Note: if you want to exclude the empty string, two possibilities:

```
if (preg_match('~(?=.)((?>[^\s/.]++|\.(?!\./))*)/?(?1)\z~A', $str))
```

or

```
if (preg_match('~((?>[^\s/.]++|\.(?!\./))*)/?(?1)\z~A', $str, $m) && $m)
```

Comment: @revo: you have forgotten the ~A

Comment: That doesn't affect result on the given sample

Comment: Some advanced regex here +1

Comment: @revo: Good point. I was trying to avoid `..` instead of `../`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge the three because you have a match_all.

I would replace preg_match_all by substr_count, because pattern is static, so it should be faster.

```
if(!preg_match("#\s|\.\./#",$file) && (substr_count($file,'/')<=1))
```

Edit: replaced ==1 by <=1 for / being optional

Edit2: We do not loose too much readability by just merging the two negative patterns